# How to split up a SpannableStringBuilder while keeping its formating?

Tags: android, html, spanned

I am working on an android project that involves parsing some HTML (parsed by Jsoup) into a SpannableStringBuilder class.

However, I need this SpannableStringBuilder class to be divided up by each new line character into a List once it is done parsing, while keeping its formatting.

Such that a spanned text of

> {"I am a spanned ***text,*\n hear** me roar"}

would turn into

> {
>   "I am a spanned ***text,***" 
>   "**hear** me roar"
>   }

I am fairly new to developing on Android, and could not find anything in the documentation about spitting spans or even getting a listing of all formatting on a spanned class to build my own. So any help is much appreciated.

Comment: tried `Spanned#subSequence(int start, int end)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure this out on my own, after looking into the method that pskink suggested.

My solution to this was

```
@Override
    public List<Spanned> parse() {
        List<Spanned> spans = new ArrayList<Spanned>();
        Spannable unsegmented = (Spannable) Html.fromHtml(base.html(), null, new ReaderTagHandler());
        //Set ColorSpan because it defaults to white text color
        unsegmented.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, unsegmented.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        //get locations of '/n'
        Stack<Integer> loc = getNewLineLocations(unsegmented);
        loc.push(unsegmented.length());

        //divides up a span by each new line character position in loc
        while (!loc.isEmpty()) {
            Integer end = loc.pop();
            Integer start = loc.isEmpty() ? 0 : loc.peek();

            spans.add(0,(Spanned) unsegmented.subSequence(start, end));
         }

        return spans;
    }

    private Stack<Integer> getNewLineLocations(Spanned unsegmented) {
        Stack<Integer> loc = new Stack<>();
        String string = unsegmented.toString();
        int next = string.indexOf('\n');
        while (next > 0) {
            //avoid chains of newline characters
            if (string.charAt(next - 1) != '\n') {
                loc.push(next);
                next = string.indexOf('\n', loc.peek() + 1);
            } else {
                next = string.indexOf('\n', next + 1);
            }
            if (next >= string.length()) next = -1;
        }
        return loc;
    }
```